# Cannot find devices on KDE Connect

Tags: networking, kde, android, kde-connect

I am in my university network and I my devices cannot find each other.
On my Android I tried add device by IP and it didn't worked. On my Laptop I cannot find this function.

The IPv4 of my computer would be like 172.29.xxx.xxx

The IPv4 of my Android device would be like 172.29.abc.ab (to show how the IP differs from each other).

Could there be any problem, that these device doesn't have the typical 192.168.. IP? 
I tried to add my computer in different ways. So my devicelist on android is right now:

- 172.29.xxx.xx
- user@172.29.xxx.xx
- user@computername

Is there anything I can try without having admin access to the network?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In more or less open networks like a university wifi it is not uncommon to use client isolation so devices on the wifi cannot connect to each other. This is a security measure. This means that you may very well be just out of luck. Sorry.

To verify if this is your problem, you could try to ping the devices or try to connect to another computer of a friend with a known to work protocol (e.g. HTTP if one of the computers has a web server running).

If this doesn't work KDE connect probably won't work either.

Comment: Well. Thats weird. Yes. You are right. I tried it. But if use VPN on both devices to connect to the exact same university network where I come from it works fine. I need to enter the IP by myself. But I can atleast connect. 
I thought there are standards when hosting an eduroam. I know that I could connect to my notebook via ssh in my university. So I thought that this might work aswell. But it looks that the university i am now has isolated the users (Even both universities work with eduroam and I can log in on both with the same IDs).
Well. Thanks. Sadly It doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect anyway, just make a **virtual network** on your laptop and connect your Android device on it.